# Building with sbuild and backports

Tags: debian, packaging, backports

We're building our package for Debian Jessie with sbuild, and so far it's working great.

There's just one detail though: we'd like to take one of the build dependencies from the Jessie backports archive.

I can't figure out how to configure the chroot to pull that package (and only that package) from backports, though.

I know how to configure the apt `sources.list` and pinning preferences on a Debian system but I couldn't find anything related to adding repositories and pinning packages from them in the `sbuild(1)` and `sbuild.conf(5)` manual pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way, thanks to @bigon on IRC.

At runtime, I now pass the following options to the `sbuild` command in addition to the ones I already had:

```
$ sbuild ... --build-dep-resolver=aptitude --extra-repository="deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" ...
```

The `--extra-repository` will add the Jessie backports as a valid archive to use in the chroot.

But unfortunately, that's not enough because the `Release` file for the backports archive has `"NotAutomatic: yes"`. As a result, even though the backports contain the dependency I need (and declared properly in `debian/control`), it doesn't get taken from there automatically.

That's where the `--build-dep-resolver=aptitude` comes into play: `aptitude` also stumbles on the missing dependency like `apt`, but then it finds it in the backports archive and automatically decides to take it (and only it) from there.

It's a bit too « automagic » for my taste, and I would prefer a way to setup some explicit pinning, but so far it's the only way I found.

Thanks @bigon!